# Second order differential with substitution

Tags: differential

[image: Question here]

Hey guys, I was doing this question and am really stuck :/

I got up to taking n as 1 and getting z'=sqrt(y)*y'

Can someone tell me where to go from here?

Edit:

I've done the first part, just not sure how to continue with part (i).

Comment: Take the derivative ò both sides and use the product rule

Comment: @Dylan Which part exactly?

Comment: Take the derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$

Comment: @Dylan Oh, I'm sorry I forgot to mention, I can do the first part, just not the part after the first part. As in I don't know how to do part (i)

Comment: You should say that in your question. I'll see if I have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $n = 1$, we get
$$z = y \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$
and
$$ \frac{dz}{dx} = \sqrt{y}\,\frac{dy}{dx} \Rightarrow z = \frac{2}{3}y^{3/2} + c_1 $$

Setting those equal to each other we get
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}y^{1/2} + \frac{c_1}{y}} $$

You now have an IVP to solve.

Comment: Thank you, I will study this.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a constant